# NodeJS app not being deployed on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to deploy an app on Heroku and getting the following error:

`Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/nodejs.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to desolate-mountain-28031.
remote:`

My repo is at https://github.com/DKSukhani/React_Node_CustomerFeedback_project

Please help.  At heroku, I have specified the buildpack as nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to move your `package.json` file to root of your directory. In your example `server` directory is not nessecary you can reconfigure your directory structure as something like this...

```
-/
  /views
    main_view.hbs
  /app
    some_logic.js
  index.js
  package.json
```